# Run a macro before Access 2010 web database application instance initializes

Tags: database, ms-access

Does anybody know how to run a macro before web database application instance initializes? I want to set up some local variables to be used in some queries which run on the load of first form. PLEASE HELP, I cant find it anywhere.

Access 2010 web database is running inside sharepoint (Access services)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just create an [AutoExec macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-macro-that-runs-when-you-open-a-database-HA010341574.aspx) that sets your variables.

Failing that, you could always have your application open a boiler-plate form, set the variables, and the close the boiler plate and open the real first form. It might happen so fast that you barely notice the boiler plate screen.

Reminder: since you are using Access Services, [you can not use any VBA](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/introduction-to-access-programming-HA010341717.aspx#BMwhenusewhat) in your application.